# CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex() giving different results in iOS11 and iOS12

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios12

```
CGImageRef        thumbnailImage = NULL;
CGImageSourceRef  imageSource = NULL;
CFDictionaryRef   createOptions = NULL;
CFStringRef       createKeys[3];
CFTypeRef         createValues[3];
CFNumberRef       thumbnailSize = 0;
UIImage * thumbnail;
NSData * squareData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(sourceImage);
NSData * thumbnailData = nil;

imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((__bridge CFDataRef)squareData,NULL);
if (imageSource)
{
    thumbnailSize = CFNumberCreate(NULL, kCFNumberIntType, &imageSize);
    if (thumbnailSize)
    {
        createKeys[0] = kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailWithTransform;
        createValues[0] = (CFTypeRef)kCFBooleanTrue;
        createKeys[1] = kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailFromImageIfAbsent;
        createValues[1] = (CFTypeRef)kCFBooleanTrue;
        createKeys[2] = kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize;
        createValues[2] = (CFTypeRef)thumbnailSize;

        createOptions = CFDictionaryCreate(NULL, (const void **) createKeys,
                createValues, sizeof(createValues)/ sizeof(createValues[0]),
                &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks,
                & kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);
        if (createOptions)
        {
            thumbnailImage = CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex(imageSource,0,createOptions);
            if(thumbnailImage)
            {
                thumbnail = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:thumbnailImage];
                if (thumbnail)
                {
                    thumbnailData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(thumbnail);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Getting different `thumbnailData.length` value for the same image in iOS12. I am trying to create a thumbnail image using `CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex()` and passing `sourceImage` as a parameter. Is it an iOS12 bug? Is there a workaround for it? I'm using iOS12 beta4.

Answer (score 2):

The data size *is* different, but the resulting image is fine. They’ve clearly made some very modest changes to the algorithm. But there is no bug here.

Personally, I notice two changes:

- In non-square images, the algorithm for determining the size of the thumbnail has obviously changed. E.g., with my sample 3500×2335px image, when I created a 100px thumbnail, it resulted in a 100×67px image in iOS 12.2, but was 100×66px in iOS 11.0.1.
- In square images, the two iOS versions both generated suitably square thumbnails. Regarding the image, itself, I could not see much of any observable difference with the naked eye. In fact, I dropped this into Photoshop and analyzed the differences (where black == no difference), it first seemed to suggest no change at all:

  [image]

  Only when I started to really pixel-peep could I detect the very modest changes. The individual channels rarely differed by more than 1 or 2 (in these `UInt8` values). Here is the same delta image, this time with the levels blown out so you can see the differences:

  [image]

Bottom line, there clearly is some change to the algorithm, but I wouldn’t characterize it as a bug. It is just different, but it works fine.

---

In an unrelated observation, your code has some leaks. If a Core Foundation method has `Create` or `Copy` in the name, you are responsible for releasing it (or, in bridged types, transferring ownership to ARC, which isn’t an option here). The static analyzer, <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, is excellent at identifying these issues.

FWIW, here’s my rendition:

```
- (UIImage * _Nullable)resizedImage:(UIImage *)sourceImage to:(NSInteger)imageSize {
    NSData *squareData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(sourceImage);
    UIImage *thumbnail = nil;

    CGImageSourceRef imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((CFDataRef)squareData, NULL);
    if (imageSource) {
        NSDictionary *createOptions = @{
            (id)kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailWithTransform: @true,
            (id)kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailFromImageIfAbsent: @true,
            (id)kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize: @(imageSize)
        };
        CGImageRef thumbnailImage = CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex(imageSource, 0, (CFDictionaryRef)createOptions);
        if (thumbnailImage) {
            thumbnail = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:thumbnailImage];
            if (thumbnail) {
                NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(thumbnail);
                // do something with `data` if you want
            }
            CFRelease(thumbnailImage);
        }
        CFRelease(imageSource);
    }

    return thumbnail;
}
```